# How can I make a reliable time-based object updating system?

Tags: game-loop, c, timestep, floating-point, fixed-point

So an object has a position, velocity, and is affected by gravity.

```
#include <simd/simd.h> // MacOS
struct Object {
    vector_float3 Translation; // Units
    vector_float3 Velocity; // Units per second
};
```

The game loop typically runs 60 times per second.

```
void ObjectUpdate(struct Object *obj) {
    obj->Velocity.y -= 9.80655/60;
    obj->Translation += obj->Velocity/60;
}
```

There are a couple problems with this approach:

- Lag exists, so the assumption of 60 updates per second being embedded in the code is not great.
- Floating point types are susceptible to precision errors at far distances from the origin, and are also more difficult to handle in some ways than integers.

I attempted to solve these with a fixed-point approach, and the use of `clock()` as well as keeping track of the time of the last update.

```
struct Object {
    vector_long3 Translation; // 65536ths of a unit
    vector_long3 Velocity; // 65536ths of a unit per second
    clock_t LastUpdate;
};
void UpdateObject(struct Object *obj) {
    const clock_t current = clock();
    const unsigned long delta = (unsigned long)((current-obj->LastUpdate)*(clock_t)65536/CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // Try to find the number of 65536ths of a second since the last update, in a way that it does not matter whether clock_t is integral or real
    obj->LastUpdate = current;
    obj->Velocity.y -= delta*642682>>16; // 642682 = 9.80655*65536
    obj->Translation -= delta*obj->Velocity>>16;
}
```

However, this suffers from other problems, most notably, being extremely chunky and unreliable. If I simply add `delta` to an accumulator and then print the accumulator, the value rises at an inconsistent rate, typically much slower than by 65536 per second.

How should I handle objects that need *'constant'* updating and their updates are contingent on time?

Comment: Safe to assume you've read [Fix Your Timestep](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/)? A fixed timestep update is the usual solution to systems that need exact consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that `clock()` measures CPU time and not absolute time. Using [`clock_gettime()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) with `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` instead of `clock()` should solve the problem. The code will have to be updated to use `struct timespec` instead of `clock_t` like so:

```
struct Object {
    vector_long3 location; // 65536ths of a unit
    vector_long3 velocity; // 65536ths of a unit per second
    long last_update;
};
void Object_update(struct Object *obj) {
    struct timespec t;
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &t))
        abort();
    const long current = t.tv_sec<<16|t.tv_nsec>>16, delta = current-obj->last_update;
    obj->last_update = current;
    obj->velocity.y -= delta*642682>>16; // 642682 = 9.80655*65536
    obj->location -= delta*obj->velocity>>16;
}
```